# Why won't this javascript code work in Wordpress post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, wordpress

I have xml file test.xml with the content

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" ?>
<LIST><script />
    <ONEP>
        <LINK>/wordpress/new_1.html</LINK>
        <CHAPTER >One 1</CHAPTER>
    </ONEP>
    <ONEP>
        <LINK>/wordpress/new_2.html</LINK>
        <CHAPTER>One 2</CHAPTER>
    </ONEP>
</LIST>
```

I want to load this content into my Wordpress page so I insert the code which is given below into my Wordpress page directly.

```
<div id="demo">
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
        loadXMLDoc();
    };

    function loadXMLDoc( ) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../wordpress/test.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send( );
    }

    function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<strong>Chapter</strong>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ONEP");

    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
        table += "<br/><a href=\".." +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("LINK")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "\">" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("CHAPTER")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</a>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }
</script>
```

Now I preview the page.Nothing is found in the page.

I even tried the code using the plugin "Jquery in posts and page" but still the code does not work.I am completely lost.Note the code works perfectly fine in normal html file.It is not working only in Wordpress page and posts.Any help please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your console give you anny error ? (Press F12 then go to console)

Comment: No error is given by the Console.

Comment: Change your script to that: `<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
alert("test");
};
</script>`

And see if it says test when you load your page.

Comment: *Edit Sorry I am getting a pop up "test" message.

Comment: Then your script isn't loaded. Probably beceause wordpress disable them by default. Try [reading](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/industry/tech-svcs/wordpress/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/) before coding

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code to get data from xml file into PHP:

```
if (file_exists('path to test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('path to test.xml');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
```

you will get multidimensional array with all tags and inner content into PHP.